# Converting byte array coming from Web service to UIImage iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am new to this technology.
I searched a lot but cant find any relevant.
In my application,I am receiving byte array from web service, my byte array which I receive from web service is

> [137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,1,195,0,0,1,195,8,2,0,0,0,215,2... ]

and I want to convert this **byte array** into **UIImage** for showing it in **UIImageView**.

Comment: In order to help you it's important to know what exactly you receive from the web service. Is it an instance of `NSArray`? If so, what's inside this array? `NSNumber`, `NSString`? Please be more descriptive in your question.

Comment: I have already mentioned response I am getting from web service in my question, [137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68...]. The data I am receiving is byte array i.e. a type of array and I want this byte array to be converted to UIImage

Comment: Is it a void * pointer? Clearly not, because otherwise the -dataWithBytes: would work fine. Nobody will help you without more code. Add the code where you retrieve the byte array in the question.

Comment: I have already implemented that code given below by Apurv, but it does not work, it gives me error and i am using ARC in my application.

Comment: As I said, update your question with the code where you get the byte array from the web service.

Comment: "it gives me error" is not enough information, please put ALL your current code and the exact error message you are getting

Comment: It would have been helpful if the missing code were provided.

Comment: @LloydMcFarlin What missing code you want, answer is below answered by Apurv. And why down-vote for that?

Comment: Hi A P.J,
Have you solved this?
If yes, may you share your solution.I am facing the same problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below constructor for UIImage.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY length:ARRAY_LENGTH];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work, any other suggestions please

Comment: Can you convert your Byte[] to NSData?

Comment: Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
Saying something like this?

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length]; Now, use this data in imageWithData, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I am getting it from web service, i am not getting way of how do I get (const void*) and lenght of it.

Comment: If you are getting the data with an NSURLConnection, you should already have NSData and length.

Answer (score 1):

The first 8 bytes in the byte array above, `\211 P N G \r \n \032 \n` (or `137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10` in decimal), reveal this to be a [`PNG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) file.

At the very least, you should be able to just save your entire byte sequence to a file, and load it using `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name` or `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`.  For example:

```
  UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myfile.png"]
                                      // myfile.png should be in the main bundle
```

(Apurv's method is more direct, and better for this reason.  But since you are having such difficulty with it, I thought I'd suggest a slightly different approach.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Base64 decode the data first. Data that is returned from many SOAP web services is base 64 encoded as well as sometimes raw data embedded in websites. It is pretty simple to do but just easiest to use a library to someone else has created.

Start by including this in your project and including the .h in this file: https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

```
NSString *base64String = @"**YOUR BYE ARRAY HERE**";
UIImage *imageOrig = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageOrig];
```

That should do it. In my previous experiences I just put what ever data blob I get over the webservice into a string then create the image using this method and it works great there is a great discussion on the details of Base64 encoding and decoding here : http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour which is what I used to create my class but Nick's code on gitHub is much better as its ARC compliant.

Comment: [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses a limited character set, typically the (26 + 26 + 10 = 62) alphanumeric characters together with '+' and '/'.  The sample byte array provided by the original poster has some decimal values which are greater than 127, e.g., 137, 195, and 215; which suggests that it is not even 7-bit ASCII, let alone base64.

Answer (score 0):

From Webservice we get array of `NSNumber`. We will have to convert it to `NSData` like this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity: [strings count]];
for( NSNumber *number in strings) {
    char byte = [number charValue];
    [data appendBytes: &byte length: 1];
}
```

Covert `NSData` to `UIImage`:

```
UIImage *imageOrig = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

We get JSON also out of `NSData`.

```
NSError *error1 = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error1];

if (error1 != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", jsonArray);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  //Use this

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY, w, h, 8, 4*w, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
CFRelease(colorSpace);
free(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY);
CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
[yourImageView setImage:newimage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

May be it will help you...

Comment: can you help me in converting data which I receive from web service to YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY i.e. byte array

Comment: you are receiving the byte array from web service if not then what you are receiving from web service

Comment: I am doing something like this, is it correct? CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate((__bridge void*)[arr valueForKey:@"ImageData"], 250.0, 250.0, 8, 4*250.0, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

Comment: use this one 
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate([arr valueForKey:@"ImageData"],50.0,50.0,100,100.0, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CFRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

    UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    [yourImageView setImage:newimage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

Comment: It gives me error as Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'void *' requires a bridged cast for [arr valueForKey:@"ImageData"]

Comment: is it not working???
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[arr valueForKey:@"ImageData"]];
[imageView setImage:img];

Comment: It crashes with -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "NSDataAdditions.h"

NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:StringImage];
UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataObj];
```

Comment: The method `dataWithBase64EncodedString:` does not appear in [Apple's documentation for the class `NSData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This method is presumably part of a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) on `NSData` that you have implemented.  As such, the code snippet above is not very useful without also knowing/having the implementation of `dataWithBase64EncodedString:`.