# Make UIImage from ByteArray getting from .Net WebService

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

My problem is same as [Converting byte array coming from Web service to UIImage iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052076/converting-byte-array-coming-from-web-service-to-uiimage-iphone?rq=1)
.Now I am storing these bytes in NSMutableArray.But the method:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY length:ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

takes arrayOfBytes as parameter.So can anyone tell me that how to convert this array in byte array. I searched a lot but unable to find relevant contents.

Comment: How did you manage to store raw bytes in an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your co-operation. But it does not help me. After a long research i found my solution. I am sharing my information so that others can get right answer.

```
        NSArray *byteArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; //strore all data here coming from server in byte formate

        unsigned c = [byteArray count];
        uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

        unsigned i;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            NSString *str = [byteArray objectAtIndex:i];
            int byte = [str intValue];
            bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
        }

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:bytes length:c];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"image %@",image);
```

Comment: Perfect ! This is how it should be done. Worked for me as well. 
Was banging my head for almost 4 hours on this. 
Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're getting the mutable array to begin with. If you're using NSURLConnection, the delegate will get NSData, so you needn't use a mutable array.  Consider getting the data using the connection asynch block method like this ...

```
NSURLRequest *myRequest = // the request you've already got working to get image data
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:myRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // image from data with no intermediate mutable array or byte array
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
 }];
```